# Are ‘Being happy’ and ‘happiness’ interchangeable?

Tags: comparison

> To study, a certain degree of **happiness** is needed.
>
> To study, a certain degree of **being happy** is needed.

Are they interchangeable?

Comment: No. The word happiness exists to save us from having to say such clunky sentences.

Comment: Hello, welcome to ELL. Here we encourage people to include some of their relevant research work and what they did to solve to problem for themselves. So please edit your question and include those. For better understanding, please look at the questions others posted. Or visit the tour section.